# Time tracking like Expert rating tests

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to create an Online Quiz script like expert rating test on ODesk or Elance.

I want to track the time, means how much time have passed and left. I also want to stop the time counter, if the user internet connection is disconnected, so that he can start from where it was disconnected.

One last thing how to disable the last questions, which were attempted by the user. I am using PHP, MySql for it.

Your ideas will be great help for me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is an awfully broad question really... Can't you go into more detail? Ask specific questions?

Comment: How are you planning to detect when the user's internet connection is disconnected?  And are you sure you want to stop the clock completely; he can still think about and work out the currently-displayed question(s).  With your spec, I can answer your hardest quiz in just a few seconds by pulling out my network cable once the question(s) are loaded.

Comment: Thanks guys for your interest.
I am narrating the complete steps.
1) Once the user starts test, his start time is saved in Db.
2) on next quiz page current time is subtracted from start time. That will be time left for the quiz
3) The user can be bounded to complete the exam, say within some specific time from start. I think it makes sense.

4) Now I have problem with how to check that his cable connection is unpluged. May be some session is usefull @ Andrzej Doyle . If have taken any exam of Expert Rating then you will came across same situation there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like this. Basically you have the right starting idea.  Create a timer table which stores start times, test id and user id.

On each page load or AJax call you check the current timestamp minus the start time to see how long has gone since they started.  If at any point it passes your limit you redirect them to the test complete page.  Don't worry about the internet connection its actually irrelevant.  This basic rule covers all.

Comment: Thanks Derek Organ for pointing me in the right direction,
One last thing is how I will disable, the last questions which were already attempted.

Thanks

Comment: use javascript/ajax to redirect automatically when time is up.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something related to this. you have to think about this to begin the idea. Create a timetable that stores begin the time, user id, or testing id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).